# unable to get image from URL to update in UIImage in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I'm trying to update the tableview cell with image from web api.
As per the below link, I tried it but it is giving nil in image even though image exist.

[Update table cell image asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814333/update-table-cell-image-asynchronously).

Below is my code please let me know where I'm missing it.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] () -> Void in
            if let url = NSURL(string: "https://myantion.eu/data/sol.svg"){
                    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                        let imageAux = UIImage(data: data as Data)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                cell.imgFlag.image = imageAux
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

The imageAux gives me nil value even though image exist

As per the below suggestions, even tried using UIWebView still no result and below is the code:

```
> let fileURL:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath:
> "https://myantion.eu/data/sol.svg")
>             let req = URLRequest(url: fileURL)
>             DispatchQueue.main.async {
>                                             cell.webVw.loadRequest(req)
>                                        }
>             
>            }
```

Comment: This sends me to a website with an image on it, but doesn't seem to be the `URL` of the image itself.

Comment: @impression7vx - this image only want to update

Comment: Not related but Don't use NS now

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift Looks like UIImage initializer takes png or jpegs, but not SVG. You'll need to perform some sort of transform or use a webview

Comment: You need Webview to show SVG type

Comment: The image type in URL is .svg not UIImage. So, better convert the .svg to .jpg or png first. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808901/svg-url-to-uiimage-ios

Comment: https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG Use this plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.svg url to UIImage iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808901/svg-url-to-uiimage-ios)

Comment: @Gereon - not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing SVGKit as given in the below reference link and it works for me.
[How to display .svg image using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift/45706892)

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] () -> Void in
            if let url = NSURL(string: "https://restcountries.eu/data/est.svg"){
                    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                        let imageAux = UIImage(data: data as Data)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let anSVGImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data as Data)
                                cell.imgFlag.image = nSVGImage.uiImage
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

in ur existing code just add one line of code:
let anSVGImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data as Data) and it worked at my end.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `WKWebView` and for me the below code is working:

```
if let svgString =
  try ? String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://myantion.eu/data/sol.svg") !) {
    self.wkWebView.loadHTMLString(svgString, baseURL: URL(string: "https://myantion.eu/data/sol.svg") !)
  }
```